# Soap query database

Tags: java

I write a opration on java soap service to query the database and then show the data I have searched on client jsp page. However, I can't show it, the variable "rs" cannot change, I don't know why? could someone help me to find the troboule?
This is the opration i create on soap service:

```
  @WebMethod(operationName = "query")
public String query(@WebParam(name = "parameter") String parameter) {
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        Connection con = data1.getConnection();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String QueryString;
        QueryString = "SELECT * from stud where name= parameter";
        rs = statement.executeQuery(QueryString);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + "\n");

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to batabase.");//TODO write your implementation code here:
    }
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? It always returns `null`, so...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question.  Maybe you mean that you can view the console output and this process that rs is an empty result set. You said rs cannot change, but you probable realize that rs stores the entire result set and you only assign it once, so it doesn't "change" if your code is working currently.

One obvious thing that is wrong is that parameter is a variable (in fact, a parameter!) But you include it inside the quotes as part of the query string.  So regardless if the function input, you are searching the database for the name "parameter"